# Probability to hit a set of pairs

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $[n] = \{1, \ldots, n\}$, and suppose that $X = \{(i,j) : i< j\}$ is some subset of $[n]^2$, and we are given only its size $|X| = x$.

Now assume I sample $y$ elements uniformly at random from $[n]$. I want to bound the probability that I didn't see any $(i,j) \in X$ (i.e. a statement of the form :"this probability is less than XXX") .

Here is what I tried:

First, if I sample two elements $i,j$ uniformly at random, the probability that $(i,j) \in X$ is $\frac{x}{{n \choose 2}}$. Denote by $S = \{s_1, \ldots, s_y \}$ the set I sampled (it is possible that there are less than $y$ different values since the choice is with replacements, but I am not sure how to overcome this issue). Define an indicator random variable $Y(s_i, s_j)$ for each $s_i < s_j \in S$ that indicates if $(s_i, s_j) \in X$, and define 
$$Y = \sum_{s_i, s_j} Y(s_i, s_j)$$

Now, $E[Y] = \frac{y(y-1)}{2} \times \frac{x}{n^2}$. The probability that I didn't see any $(s_i, s_j) \in X$ is the probability that $Y = 0$. But here is where I got stuck: Markov's inequality works in the other way (it can bound that probability that $Y$ is much bigger than $E[Y]$). Moreover, I am not sure how to overcome the case that there are repetitions in $S$ (in that case I don't know how many random variables I have)

Comment: It’s not entirely clear whether you’re looking at ordered or at unordered pairs. When you say that the probability that $\langle i,j\rangle\in X$ is $\frac{x}{n^2}$, you’re clearly talking about ordered pairs, and that probability is at most $\frac{n-1}{2n}$ even if $X$ is everything above the diagonal in $[n]^2$. But you define the $Y(s_i,s_j)$ only for $s_i<s_j$, irrespective of the order of $i$ and $j$, which means that you’re actually looking at unordered pairs.

Comment: The set $X$ has only pairs $(i, j)$ such that $i<j$. When I pick two random elements uniformly at random, I have $n^2$ options, but only $x$ out of them are in $X$. Perhaps the definition of the $Y()$ is wrong - I don't think that my solution is correct

Comment: When you take your sample $S$, which ordered pairs to you actually consider? Some possibilities are: $\langle s_i,s_j\rangle$ with $i<j$; $\langle s_i,s_j\rangle$ with $s_i<s_j$, the ones that you used to define the $Y$s; $\langle s_i,s_{i+1}\rangle$, using only consecutive observations.

Comment: Basically I want to consider "as much as I can". Suppose that $S = \{1,4,6\}$. Then I can only consider $(1,4), (1,4), (4,6)$ because any other option has probability $0$ to be in $X$ (because $X$ has only pairs $i < j$)

Comment: But if you consider only those pairs $\langle s_i,s_j\rangle$ in which $s_i<s_j$, you’re either artificially inflating the probability that you observe a member of $X$ or using a sample space different from $[n]^2$, namely, the set of **unordered** pairs from $[n]$.

Comment: I see. So it should be $x/{n \choose 2}$ instead?

Comment: The number of unordered pairs of unordered pairs of distinct elements of $[n]$ is $\binom{n}2$; that’s the effective size of your sample space if you consider only pairs with first component less than second component. (I have to go offline now, but I’ll check back later.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks. Do you have an idea how to overcome the issue that there might be less different pairs than $y(y-1)/2$?